# What is the difference between /* ...*/ and /** ... */

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've noticed that Eclipse prints diferent formats to comments:

```
/* Eclipse prints it in green 
*/
```

or if you write:

```
/** Eclipse prints it in blue
*/
```

What is the difference between these 2 kind of comments?

Comment: The latter is Javadoc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/* 
* It is multi-line comment in Java
*
*/

/** 
* It is a Javadoc. Can be found above methods and Class definitions.
*
*
*/
```

Here is a excerpt from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) regarding Javadoc:

> A Javadoc comment is set off from code by standard multi-line comment
>   tags /* and */. The opening tag (called begin-comment delimiter), has
>   an extra asterisk, as in /**.
>
> ```
> The first paragraph is a description of the method documented.
> Following the description are a varying number of descriptive tags, signifying:
>     The parameters of the method (@param)
>     What the method returns (@return)
>     Any exceptions the method may throw (@throws)
>     Other less-common tags such as @see (a "see also" tag)
> ```

**Class level Javadoc Example:**

```
/**
 * @author      Firstname Lastname <address @ example.com>
 * @version     1.6                 (current version number of program)
 * @since       2010-03-31          (the version of the package this class was first added to)
 */
public class Test {
    // class body
}
```

**Method level Javadoc Example:**

```
/**
 * Short one line description.                           
 * <p>
 * Longer description. If there were any, it would be    
 * here.
 * <p>
 * And even more explanations to follow in consecutive
 * paragraphs separated by HTML paragraph breaks.
 *
 * @param  variable Description text text text.          
 * @return Description text text text.
 */
public int methodName (...) {
    // method body with a return statement
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/* ... */
```

is simply a comment.

```
/** ... */
```

is a javadoc, which can then be converted into a nice HTML documentation by a tool called, oddly enough, `javadoc`. This tool considers the javadoc comment itself, the declaration of the class/interface/method, and any other super/subclass implementations/contracts (in creating the "specified by" and "overrides" information on methods, for example). The most noteworthy example of this is the [Java SE API doc itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

This documentation comment includes its own markup, for example `@see Bar`. It can specify programmatical considerations such as method parameters and their descriptions, the method's return type, the exceptions the method is declared to throw and the circumstances under which they would be thrown, and other information.

For example, `ArrayList#toArray()` is documented as

> `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
>   sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the
>   returned array is that of the specified array. If the list fits in the
>   specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is
>   allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of
>   this list.
>
> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the
>   array has more elements than the list), the element in the array
>   immediately following the end of the collection is set to null. (This
>   is useful in determining the length of the list only if the caller
>   knows that the list does not contain any null elements.)
>
> **Specified by:**
>       toArray in interface Collection
>   **Specified by:**
>       toArray in interface List
>   **Overrides:**
>       toArray in class AbstractCollection
>   **Type Parameters:**
>       `T` - the runtime type of the array to contain the collection
>   **Parameters:**
>       `a` - the array into which the elements of the list are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.
>   **Returns:**
>       an array containing the elements of the list
>   **Throws:**
>       `ArrayStoreException` - if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this list
>       `NullPointerException` - if the specified array is null

from

```
 /**
 * Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
 * sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned
 * array is that of the specified array.  If the list fits in the
 * specified array, it is returned therein.  Otherwise, a new array is
 * allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of
 * this list.
 *
 * <p>If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare
 * (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in
 * the array immediately following the end of the collection is set to
 * <tt>null</tt>.  (This is useful in determining the length of the
 * list <i>only</i> if the caller knows that the list does not contain
 * any null elements.)
 *
 * @param a the array into which the elements of the list are to
 *          be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the
 *          same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.
 * @return an array containing the elements of the list
 * @throws ArrayStoreException if the runtime type of the specified array
 *         is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in
 *         this list
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified array is null
 */
```

Comment: If only the people knew [the power of JavaDoc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGa6MAibjzA)

Answer (score 0):

They are 3 kinds of comments in java :

**Single ligne comment**

```
// This is a single line comment
```

**Multi-line comment**

```
/* This is a
multi-line comment */
```

**Documentation comment**

```
/**
* This is a <b>documentation comment</b>
*/
```

The compiler will ignore all of them but the javadoc tool will uses doc comments for javadoc  generation, you can use in there `HTML` formatting. You also can use tag like `@see` or `@author`

Comment: Not just HTML--there is a set of javadoc-specific tags.